# Expose a feed for ACL restricted content to crawl via feeds

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Hey guys, I'm trying to sync 2 sites on drupal, ideally the route to go would be to use feeds, however the content I'm trying to sync is restricted to users with a role they pay to have.

That means the other site can't see the feed because it gets denied the content. How would I go about exposing this feed so feeds can crawl it on the other site?

Comment: Is the title related to the question content?

Comment: Can you open it to the server IP?

Comment: oops! I'll fix the title, lol.

@Ashley - No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a module that outputs as rss, I used an access callback to validate the host and a key I appended in the url of the feed. works pretty well.

Comment: Could you post some code for your module? Specifically the validation portion? Also, you can use Views (or Views Bonus Pack) to create the feed. Not sure if that's what the OP went with or not, sounds like he already had the feed set up.